# System properties in unit tests when run with intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, system-properties, p12

I m running a unit test using the intellij runner.

In the main method of the app, we set the keystore to the value:

```
/home/oozen/workspace/wakeup/src/main/resources/Certif.p12

public void run(String... args){
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", vodafoneKeystore);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", vodafoneKeystorePassword);
        logger.info(" **************** WakeUpApp **************** ");
        logger.info("vodafoneKeystore is set to {}", vodafoneKeystore);
    }
```

**This works ok on production. But not on unit tests when I run with intellij.**

In the tests, when i log the result of getProperty, i see what we set in the code.

In the beginning of my test method, i can see the value is correctly set:

```
    logger.info(" ################## KEYSTORE : {}", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));

 ################## KEYSTORE : /home/oozen/workspace/wakeup/src/main/resources/Certif.p12
```

But during the handshake, i see the message: `no certificate found` resulting in failure in the authentication.

**Any ideas as to why?**

I know that I can run the test with an arg : ... `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=...`
But i donT want to.. :)

Also, @Thiru shows a way to set it externally, but my aim is to be able to set it from the code and to be able to rely on it in the unit tests.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you specify absolute path to the keystore file? Does it exist on the system? You can also test if the file is loaded by e.g. `File.exists()` method. If file exists looks like the issue is not fith loading the file but how the certificate is imported into the java store that runs your tests (it is specified as **JRE** in Run/Debug Configuration).

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish using Path Variables in Preferences.

Follow the steps below:

- Open Preference -> Path Variables
- Click the `+` icon
- Add the property name and value
- Click apply

Please refer to the below image

[image]

Comment: that's sth.. but this also means that whatever we set in the code will be ignored